# Get scroll position using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Strange request, but I need to get the current browser scroll position as a variable. What js or jquery function should I use? I need it to figure out what elements to display on the side. I've found a few things online but nothing that works for my div, just the full page.

Answer (score 123, accepted):

cross browser variant

```
$(document).scrollTop();
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer; $('body').scrollTop() doesn't work in IE.

Comment: try $('html, body').scrollTop();

Comment: working solution https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_css_scrolltop_get

Answer (score 34):

Older IE and Firefox browsers attach the scrollbar to the `documentElement`, or what would be the `<html>` tag in HTML.

All other browsers attach the scrollbar to `document.body`, or what would be the `<body>` tag in HTML.

The correct solution would be to check which one to use, depending on browser

```
var doc = document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement : document.body;
var s   = $(doc).scrollTop();
```

jQuery does make this a little easier, when passing in either `window` or `document` jQuery's `scrollTop` does a similar check and figures it out, so either of these should work cross-browser

```
var s = $(document).scrollTop();
```

or

```
var s = $(window).scrollTop();
```

[**jQuery scrollTop() docs**](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/)

> Description: Get the current vertical position of the scroll bar for
>   the first element in the set of matched elements or set the vertical
>   position of the scroll bar for every matched element.

---

> ...nothing that works for my div, just the full page

If it's for a DIV, you'd have to target the element that has the scrollbar attached, to get the scrolled amount

```
$('div').scrollTop();
```

If you need to get the elements distance from the top of the document, you can also do

```
$('div').offset().top
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe the best method with jQuery is using [`.scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/):

```
var pos = $('body').scrollTop();
```

Comment: What differs this answer by @adeneo's one?

Comment: Daryl's is over 7% smaller, therefor more efficient ;)

Comment: @JasonSperske :D now cause of you I have to make another coffee

Comment: Crap, now I had to change mine?

Answer (score 1):

Use [scrollTop()](http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/) to get or set the scroll position.