# jquery body selector seems to not work

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-selectors, null, scrolltop

I have a problem with the ().scrollTop() function. I want to check if the body of my html is scrolled. I have tried this code:

```
p = $('body').scrollTop();
console.log(p);
```

also instead of the ('body') in the selector I tried (document.body), ("#ID").

Problem is, that in the console i always get a return value of "null" instead of "0". I tried the same with (window), then it returns "0" and works fine. But in my case I can not use (window) because I have to set the overflow of html to hidden. The body of the document is scrollable and has height/width 100%, so I dont understand why it is not working..

Thanks a lot for your help!!

Comment: Why would the body be scrollable instead of the window ?

Comment: @adeneo : http://stackoverflow.com/a/14886047/1719752

Comment: @MilindAnantwar - That moron has the wrong answer !

Comment: @adeneo : LOL yeah....

Answer (score 0):

use `document` instead of `body`:

```
$(document).scrollTop();
```

Comment: $(document).scrollTop(); would return the scrollValue of the <html>

The problem is, like I wrote before, that I dont want the scrollValue of the entire HTML because this would always be "0" as I have overflow:hidden on my <html>. Instead I want the Value for the <body>-element.

Comment: @user1430544 : would be great if you can create the fiddle

Answer (score 0):

you may want to use this :

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="wrap">
you html ...
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

js:

```
p=$("#wrap").scrollTop()
console.log(p)
```

Comment: I want to get the current scroll value, in the end I want it to return  "0" for being at the top or eg. "50" if i scrolled the body down for 50 pixels.. Problem is that i dont get the scrollvalue of body which should be "0" instead I get "null"

Comment: @user1430544 sorry my bad , then milind answer is correct .

Comment: Anyway , scroll top will work on something that have a parent dom , try wrapping the whole content of your body in a container div

Comment: No, it would be correct if I wanted to get the scrollValue of the <html> instead i search for the scrollValue of <body>..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/gw6yb/1/   here is the project, the problem is the shadow under the navBar which I try to inicialize with jquery

Comment: @user1430544 this will work just clean up your code please.http://jsfiddle.net/prollygeek/gw6yb/3/