# JS get scroll instance height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am looking to get a method to dynamically get scroll position height instance as long as I scroll page, update CSS as well.

I used this snippet, however the value of `bodyHeight` is fixed on first page load, not updating while scroll and the CSS as well.

```
var bodyHeight = $('body').scrollTop();
var fixedTop = bodyHeight - 50;//(50)topnav height
$('.fixed-inner').css('top', fixedTop + 'px');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var bodyHeight = $(window).scrollTop();
var fixedTop = bodyHeight - 50;//(50)topnav height
$('.fixed-inner').css('top', fixedTop + 'px');
```

Comment: That was copy/paste. Nothing new here.

Comment: No. It is $(window).scrollTop() in my code instead of $('body').scrollTop()

Answer (score 1):

Try with something similar to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        div#main{
            background-color:green;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<br /><br /><br /><br />
<div id="main" style="height:300px; position:relative; overflow:scroll;">
    <div class="stairsImage" style="height:500px; width:300px; background-color:yellow; ">
       <h1 id="testName">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
    </div>
</div>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.6/jquery.js"></script> 

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
//-------------------------
   $(window).scroll(function(){
      var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
        console.log(wScroll);

      $("#testName").css({'transform' : 'translate(0px, '+ wScroll +'px)'});

   });  
//-------------------------
   $("div#main").scroll(function(){
      var wScroll = $(this).scrollTop();
        console.log(wScroll);

      $("#testName").css({'transform' : 'translate(0px, '+ wScroll +'px)'});

   }) 
});
</script>       
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That was hard and mess with everything. Need more nicer way!

Comment: Focus on the snipped between: //-------------------------

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps you

```
$(window).scroll(function () { 
    //You've scrolled this much:
       $('div').text("The scrool position is " + $ (window).scrollTop() + " pxs");
});
```

jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/luanranufe/sLzq3nLg/)

good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to recalculate the bodyHeight when you scroll the page, and there is an jquery event for that, and you can have `bodyHeight` as a global variable.

```
var bodyHeight = $('body').scrollTop();
$(window).scroll(function () { 
    //recalculate the value every time the user scroll
    var bodyHeight = $(window).scrollTop();
    //doSomething()
});
```

further reading:

- [How do I determine height and scrolling position of window in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/303767/how-do-i-determine-height-and-scrolling-position-of-window-in-jquery)
- [Get scroll position using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14886038/get-scroll-position-using-jquery)